# How to Create GeneratePresignedUrlRequest from s3Object?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, encryption, pre-signed-url

I'm trying to make encryption with Java and AWS. I'm trying to create a url that can allow to download decrypted file. I'm using client side symmetric key.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/encrypt-client-side-symmetric-master-key.html

Encryption process works just fine. But I can't get url of decrypted file.

Now, this is working

```
S3Object s3Object = amazonS3EncryptionClient.getObject(content.getBucketName(), content.getContentUrl());
byte[] array = IOUtils.toByteArray(s3Object.getObjectContent());
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("example.txt"), array);
```

But I need `GeneratePresignedUrlRequest`, then I get my url like this:

```
URL url = amazonS3EncryptionClient.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

I tried to instantiate a new `GeneratePresignedUrlRequest`. Then I create a url, but I can reach the encrypted file this way.

I'm guessing I need to use my `s3Object` to create decrypted file's url. I appreciate any help.